# What is the reason of this data abort in ZYNQ 7000 (armA9)?

Tags: arm, abort, zynq

I'm using ZYNQ 7000 SoC which has 2 arm A9 cores, core0 and core1. Sometimes a data abort happens in my core1 code (bare metal). At the default data abort handler `Xil_DataAbortHandler`, it says the `FaultStatus` is 0x1e, and the `DataAbortAddr` is 0x2001bc9c.

I use `readelf -s a.elf` to get the symbol table, and find no function address match the exact 0x2001bc9c. The closest function is `Xil_L2CacheDisable` at address 2001bc64. Does this mean that the data abort is from `Xil_L2CacheDisable`? This function is a bsp library function provided by Xilinx. I'm using it for direct access to the shared memory for the 2 cores.

The global variable `u32 DataAbortAddr` is captured by the following assembly:

```
DataAbortHandler:               /* Data Abort handler */
#ifdef CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_775420
    dsb
#endif
    stmdb   sp!,{r0-r3,r12,lr}      /* state save from compiled code */
    ldr     r0, =DataAbortAddr
    sub     r1, lr, #8
    str     r1, [r0]                    /* Stores instruction causing data abort */

    bl  DataAbortInterrupt      /*DataAbortInterrupt :call C function here */

    ldmia   sp!,{r0-r3,r12,lr}      /* state restore from compiled code */

    subs    pc, lr, #8          /* points to the instruction that caused the Data Abort exception */
```

The `FaultStatus` is captured in `DataAbortInterrupt`

```c
#define mfcp(rn)    ({u32 rval = 0U; \
             __asm__ __volatile__(\
               "mrc " rn "\n"\
               : "=r" (rval)\
             );\
             rval;\
             })
#endif
#define XREG_CP15_DATA_FAULT_STATUS     "cp15:0:c5:c0:0"

u32 FaultStatus = mfcp(XREG_CP15_DATA_FAULT_STATUS);
```

Answer (score 1):

ZYNQ 7000 SoC is based on ARMv7, all retrieved from ARMv7 reference manual.

`"cp15:0:c5:c0:0"` is reading `DFSR, Data Fault Status Register`.
Value `0x1E` is 'Fault Status' bits in DFSR register ([DFSR Link](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/System-Level-Architecture/System-Control-Registers-in-a-VMSA-implementation/VMSA-System-control-registers-descriptions--in-register-order/DFSR--Data-Fault-Status-Register--VMSA))

And in this case means "Synchronous parity error on translation table walk, Second level" (if you using short-descriptor translation table format) ([FSR encodings](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/c/System-Level-Architecture/Virtual-Memory-System-Architecture--VMSA-/Exception-reporting-in-a-VMSA-implementation/Fault-reporting-in-PL1-modes?lang=en#CBHHADIB)). 
Which is likely ECC throwing exception due to bad memory chip.

It's not clear how `DataAbortAddr` is acquired. But I'm quite confident that's **data memory address**, not instruction address. Or by other words exception occurs when some instruction is reading data word at address `0x2001bc9c`.

In order to get instruction address you would need backtrace `PC`/`LR` registers to the point where exception happens.

Also I'd recommend to use `objdump` instead of `readelf` tool to search for instructions.